# SQL select statement is finding something that should not exist in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sql statement for making a view

```
create view RecordYearsTwo 
as
    select 
        Record.RecordID, RecordValue.Value 
    from 
        Record 
    join 
        RecordValue on Record.RecordID = RecordValue.RecordID
    where 
        len(RecordValue.Value) = 4 
        and RecordValue.Value like '[16-20][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
        and RecordValue.Value like '%[16-20][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
        and RecordValue.Value != '26 Mar 1850';
```

When I then run

```
select * 
from Record
join RecordYearsTwo on Record.RecordID = RecordYearsTwo.RecordID 
where cast(RecordYearsTwo.Value as int) >= 1800
```

I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '26 Mar 1850' to data type int.

My understanding is that '26 Mar 1850' shouldn't even exist in my view because the length of everything in my view should be 4 and I specifically said should not equal '26 Mar 1850'

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you dropped the view, then re-created it?  Side note:  It would be better to be storing the date in a SARGable format, preferrably ISO: `YYYY-MM-DD` (so, `'1850-03-26`, assuming you can't store it as a date object).  This would prevent you from even needing to do the conversion, among other things.

Comment: SQL Server could decide to merge the where clauses together.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* In this case, the question is lacking the table definitions. For example, if `RecordValue.Value` is of type `int`, that might cause this error. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The criteria for that datestamp isn't needed.
Because even the first criteria wouldn't accept it (to long).

And those LIKE criteria don't need the % if only 4 characters are expected.

```
create view RecordYearsTwo as
select rec.RecordID, val.Value 
from Record rec
join RecordValue val on val.RecordID = rec.RecordID
where len(val.Value) = 4 
  and (val.Value like '1[6-9][0-9][0-9]' or val.Value like '20[0-9][0-9]')
```

And to avoid the error you could use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) instead.

```
select * 
from Record
join RecordYearsTwo on Record.RecordID = RecordYearsTwo.RecordID 
where try_cast(RecordYearsTwo.Value as int) >= 1800
```

Answer (score 0):

With multiple expressions in the where clause, you can't guarantee what order they get executed in. Try:

```
create view RecordYearsTwo as
select r.RecordID, v.Value 
from Record r
join (
    select *
    from RecordValue
    where len(Value) = 4 
) v on r.RecordID = v.RecordID
where v.Value like '[16-20][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
    and v.Value like '%[16-20][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your view conditions do not make sense.  I think you want:

```
create view RecordYearsTwo as
    select r.RecordID, rv.Value 
    from Record r join
         RecordValue rv
         on r.RecordID = rv.RecordID
    where len(rv.Value) = 4 
          try_convert(int, rv.Value) >= 1600 and
          try_convert(int, rv.Value) < 2100;
```

Your logic doesn't make sense.  I find this amusing:  `'v.Value like '[16-20][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'`.  That `like` pattern says to get any `'1'`, any character between `'6'` and `'2'` (which is none), and any `'0'`.  I understand what you mean, but SQL Server does not.

Then, the view does not get executed first.  You have no idea what the order of execution is, so for your query, you want `try_convert()` again:

```
select * 
from Record join r
     RecordYearsTwo ry2
     on r.RecordID = ry2.RecordID 
where try_convert(int, ry2.Value) >= 1800
```